# Upload file outside web root directory

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

i want to upload images outside web root directory, but i don't know how to do it. 
For example i want to put images in **var/media3/**, i set the media directory to permissions 777, now i need to modify the code to put images because that can not work.
I tryed even using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but it doesn't work (and honestly I have never tried this kind of thing).

This is the upload.php script:

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'var/media3/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){ // <--The problem is in this string, it won't work
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

Thanks XD

Comment: `var/media3/` is a relative path to the current working dir not the file system root

Comment: `../var/media3/` try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a leading slash `/var/media`

Comment: wow it was easier than I expected! Thanks a lot PeeHaa and Parris! It works!